# Add custom column to Eclipse Problems View

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am creating an Eclipse Plugin. I want to add a column to the Eclipse Problem view that allows me to select from a drop down menu of preset selections. How would I go about adding this functionality? I would like to add it to the current Eclipse Problems View without having to create my own custom Problems View.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is probably not possible to add a column there, as the logical content of that view is provided by its content provider.

However, you can at least add actions to the issues (that is, the real objects being shown in the problems view) by using [object contributions](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/workbench_basicext_popupMenus.htm). They will occur in the popup menu of an issue and they have the advantage of occuring *everywhere*, where a popup for issues exists, not only in the problems view.

You might also be able to solve your problem by adding a new button or menu item to the toolbar of the problems view (using so called [view actions](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/workbench_basicext_viewActions.htm)), which can then invoke your selection.

If you want to compare those different alternatives, you may also want to have a look at the general overview of how to [extend the Eclipse workbench UI](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/workbench_basicext.htm).

Comment: I was hoping that the column would display this data for the user and the user can change if if needed. The items you mentioned will work for changing it but is there a way to just add the column to display the data?

Comment: Why are you asking the same question again? I told you what is possible and what is not possible.

Comment: Sorry if the wording made it like I was asking the same question. I just wanted to be sure that no custom columns could be added to the problem view, and not just editable ones. Thank you for your help Bananewizen.